# How to toggle ng-class in this notificationDirective from within the Controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

http://plnkr.co/edit/I30bgBrsO1Wo3JCcbUmK?p=preview

The ng-class toggle in the directive html:
`ng-class="{true: "main.success", false: "main.error"}`

Full HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
    <notification-msg></notification-msg>

    <button ng-click="main.openAlert('success')">Click for success</button>

    <button ng-click="main.openAlert('error')">Click for error</button>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="alert.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

MainCtrl

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['notification-directives'])
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        var vm = this;

        vm.openAlert = function(m) {
            console.log(m);
            vm.message = m;
            vm.notification = m;

            // trying to toggle the ng-class in the directive here
            if (m === 'success') {
                vm.success = true;
            } else if (m === 'error') {
                vm.error = false;
            }
       }
    }]);
})();
```

The Notification Directive

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('notification-directives', [])
    .directive('notificationMsg', function () {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: 
                '<section ng-show="main.notification" ' +
                    'class="ng-notification"> ' +
                    '<p class="notify-msg">{{main.message}}</p> ' +
                    '<div class="notify-bg ng-class="{true: "main.success", false: "main.error"} success"></div> ' +
                '</section>'
        };
    });
})();
```

Comment: simply call  vm.openAlert('success'); somewhere in your maincontroller

Comment: @micha I have that function in my main controller now, but how would you write the ng-class in the template of the directive?

Comment: I dont understand what the problem is.  You stated "Note the goal here is to not to use an ng-click toggle values from inside the markup, but from inside the Main Controller." is this what you want to do?  Or is your problem not being able to work the ng-class properly?  I'm rather confused...

Comment: if the complete section should have background color you can use class="ng-notification  {{main.message}}" since the the string in main.message  equals the classes you want to add

Comment: @yangli The button success is suppose to add the class `.success` to the ng-notification. Or if the user clicks the button error is suppose to add the class `.error` to the the ng-notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To form an if clause in your `ng-class` simply use

```
ng-class="main.success?'success':'error'"
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ODpUzgWZvVdWkTrQZUjk?p=preview) is your plunker modified, so that it works. Unfortunately I had to add a template file to make the quotations easier readable.

Additionally I removed your `vm.error` and toggle `vm.success` between true and false.

Comment: Ah thanks :D Yeah I should use actual HTML templates more often instead of embedding the HTML in the directive...

Answer (score 1):

if the complete section should have background color you can use

```
class="ng-notification  {{main.message}}"
```

since the the string in main.message  equals the classes you want to add.

then u can hide with main.openAlert(' ')   if you use

```
ng-show="(main.message)"
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/GPlhqG19BwdgAhsOwt31?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that will make this work

View [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/XG50b01araZ0xL3zmy02?p=preview)

First use 1 variable to determine fail or success, in my case I used 'success' which is true when it is a success and a false when it is an error

```
vm.openAlert = function(m) {
  console.log(m);
  vm.message = m;
  vm.notification = m;

  vm.success = (m === 'success');
}
```

Second in your directive change the ng-class location and ng-class string

```
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: 
            '<section ng-show="main.notification" ' +
                  'class="ng-notification" ng-class="{success: main.success, error: !main.success}"> ' +
                  '<p class="notify-msg">{{main.message}}</p> ' +
                  '<div class="notify-bg></div> ' +
              '</section>'
    };
```

And you're done!

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a very clean way to do it too :)